# 直接的に保存できない点字ファイルをPowerShellなどで自動的にコンバートできますか？

Tags: powershell

以下のことはPowerShellで可能でしょうか？

BASE 形式の点字ファイルは通常では文字化けして開けないのですが、MyEdit というテキストエディタは点字ファイルをコンバートして通常のひらがなで表示してくれます。
その文章をコピペすれば使えるのですが、可能なら手数を省くために、表示された画面のテキストをコピペして自動で元のファイル名でテキストファイルに保存したいのです。

この目的は、人力でやる以下を省くためです。
オール選択→コピー→貼り付け→ファイル名をつけて保存という手間を省くためです。

これは可能でしょうか？

ソフトウェアは点字ファイルの開けるテキストエディタです。
行程としては、

クリックしたらすぐに開く
↓
そのまま、ひらがなで表示される
↓
自動的にコピー
↓
テキストファイルとして元の開いたファイルの名前で保存

この行程をbatファイルやPowerShellやVBScriptで自動化したいのです。

ソフトウェアはMyEditというテキストエディタです。
http://talk-pc.sakura.ne.jp/myedit_basis.html

体験版
https://www.aok-net.com/dlpage/pctalker.neo.trial.html

サンプル点字ファイル
https://www.mhlw.go.jp/tenji/bse/file01-01.BSE

MyEditだと、通常の文章で開きます。

こんなことができるそふとです
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4yacKtnI5A

直接的には編集禁止になって、上書きできないですが、文字を選択、コピーすれば実質的に別のテキストエディタに貼り付ければ保存は出来ますので自動化できれば、実質コンバートソフトになります。
保存する場合はUTF-8で希望です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: "Power Automate Desktop" などの自動化ツールを検討した方がよさそうな気もします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BASE 形式の点字ファイルを、その点字列が意味している平仮名文字列にした上で、テキストファイルとして保存したい、という話だと理解しました。

#### 直接変換しちゃう方法

であれば、テキストエディタを介することなく、直接プログラムで変換してしまうのが早そうです。

BASE 形式のファイルフォーマットについての詳しい解説を見つけることができませんでしたが、第三者の解析（[例](http://takeno.iee.niit.ac.jp/%7Efoo/thesis/2005/nishi.pdf)）によるとヘッダーと本文があって、本文は [Braille ASCII](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_ASCII) で書かれたもののようです。本文だけコンバートできれば良いのであれば簡単そうです。

そうであるならば、ヘッダーは無視しつつ本文を前から順番に処理するプログラムを書けば良さそうです。たとえば Braille ASCII と日本語点字における文字の対応付けを辞書として覚えておいて、1 文字ずつ変換し出力していくプログラムをお好きなスクリプトで書けば良いでしょう（より丁寧にやるなら濁点・半濁点の処理が要るでしょう）。

#### 自動化ツールを使う方法

スクリプトを書かずに解決したいのであれば、GUI ツールの操作を自動化するツールというものが世の中にはあるので、それを使うのが良さそうです（多くは有償ですが……）。たとえば Power Automate Desktop など。